# What Component IDs should I search for to detect whether the Office 2010 PIA's are Installed

Tags: installation, ms-office, office-2010

I'm creating a plug-in for Office 2010 and need to detect on install whether the Office 2010 PIA's are installed.

I have done this for 2003 and 2007 but cannot find the Component ID's for 2010 does anyone know what they are?

thanks,
Ed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do a search for the component ID for the PIA (primary interop assembly) applicable to the component of office you need from the list below:

```
{EA7564AC-C67D-4868-BE5C-26E4FC2223FF}   Excel
{4153F732-D670-4E44-8AB7-500F2B576BDA}   InfoPath
{1D844339-3DAE-413E-BC13-62D6A52816B2}   Outlook
{EECBA6B8-3A62-44AD-99EB-8666265466F9}   PowerPoint
{3EA123B5-6316-452E-9D51-A489E06E2347}   Visio
{8B74A499-37F8-4DEA-B5A0-D72FC501CEFA}   Word
{957A4EC0-E67B-4E86-A383-6AF7270B216A}   Project
{B2279272-3FD2-434D-B94E-E4E0F8561AC4}   Forms 2.0
{011B9112-EBB1-4A6C-86CB-C2FDC9EA7B0E}   Graph
{7102C98C-EF47-4F04-A227-FE33650BF954}   Smart Tag
{64E2917E-AA13-4CA4-BFFE-EA6EDA3AFCB4}   Office Shared
```

E.g. if you are writing a Word add-in, then you only really need to check for the PIA with the GUID {8B74A499-37F8-4DEA-B5A0-D72FC501CEFA}

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/9bde5b41-f5da-4918-b62b-8ab24479ef93)

Microsoft have recently released the PIAs for 2010 seperately. Available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=938fe8ad-583b-4bd7-a345-23250dc15855)

If you need to support Office 2013, the component Ids are documented here:
[Office 2013 PIA component Ids](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1fd8690a-812c-49f9-a77e-e19f24de7c4e/office-2013-pia-component-ids)

Comment: Hi all, I installed Office 2010 PIA without installing Office 2010, and I cannot find the keys listed above.

Comment: Hi Peter-I downloaded the standalone msi to check if the guids had changed, and they appear the same. You mentioned keys-bare in mind that these are not registry keys or values, they are the guids representing components which are installed in Windows. So the idea is you do a component search on the guid within an installer to see if the particular PIA you require exists on the target system.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to install PIA separately or check the version of installed PIA if you target .NET Framework 4 and above.
[Check this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/06/04/creating-an-add-in-for-office-2007-and-office-2010-that-quot-lights-up-quot-on-office-2010-mclean-schofield.aspx).

> When you compile an add-in project that targets the .NET Framework 4,
>   by default **the type information for all the PIA types referenced in
>   the add-in code is embedded in the add-in assembly**. At run time, this
>   type information is used to resolve calls to the underlying COM type,
>   rather than relying on type information in the PIAs.

Just check in your project that the reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` has the correct version and `EmbedInteropTypes` set to `true`.